# How make runtime.exec() working on multi-OS in Java?

Tags: java, runtime, runtime.exec

I call a runtime execution on OSX adding "/bin/bash", "-c" before the command, such as:

```
Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();  
Process process = runtime.exec(new String[] { "/bin/bash", "-c", cmd });
```

I know that it is different for Windows and Linux. How can I make sure that my runtime command works on multi-OS?

Thank you.

Comment: You'll have to check the operating system and conditionally do the commands.  What exactly are you trying to do?  Maybe it will be possible to do it in a more abstract way that won't be OS dependent.  (Likely not though if you're wanting to run complex scripts or something.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use something like:

```
    String osName = System.getProperty("os.name");
    if(osName.startsWith("Windows")) {
        // windows code
    } else {
        if(osName.startsWith("Linux") {
             // linux code
        } else {
             // mac code
        }
    }
```

Disclaimer: This is just orientative. There are still many corner cases (e.g. FreeBSD) that you need to test to get correct behavior.